# Two groups of overlayed calendars in Outlook (2016)?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I know it's possible to overlay calendars in Outlook (2016) or to view them separately, side-by-side:

[Calendar 1 / Calendar 2] or [Calendar 1] [Calendar 2]

I would like to have two groups of overlayed calendars, because I share calendars with several colleagues, but would like to be able to focus on my own calendars. So something like:

[Calendar 1 / Calendar 2] [Cal. A / B / C D]

Is this possible, and if yes, how? My google-fu failed me, but maybe there is no such option in stock Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

Right click the calendar icon in Outlook (the one in the bottom left) and choose "Open in new window".
This will create a new calendar window with which you can make another overlaid calendar set.

Comment: Not exactly what I had in mind, so I won't mark it as the accepted answer, but definitely a good workaround. Thanks!

Comment: Having them in the same window is not really an option unfortunately.  You can suggest features to MS if that's something you would like to be able to do.  https://office365.uservoice.com